# Distinguish Wikipedia Disambiguations from Normal Pages

Tags: xpath, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Currently, I'm attempting to retrieve the content of a given Wikipedia page to a plain text file. Using XPath, I have code that does this perfectly. However, there is just one simple problem: some pages on Wikipedia are disambiguation pages.

Now, this in itself isn't dramatic. I've written an XPath expression that retrieves the first link of a Wikipedia disambiguation page: `(/html/body/div[@id='content']/div[@id='bodyContent']//a[starts-with(@href, '/wiki')]/@href)[1]`.  This means I can just use that first link as the page I'm trying to retrieve content from.

No, the real problem is that I haven't found any way to know *when* to use that code (the one to retrieve the first link from a disambiguation page) or the other piece of code (the one that directly gets content from the interesting page, the non-disambiguation one). Indeed, I can't seem to find a way to distinguish a disambiguated page from a normal one.

So far, I've tried:

Looking at the source of a disambiguated page and comparing it with a normal one: I can't find a difference.

Looking at the content on both types of pages: here, the only difference is that some pages say 'This page may refer to' at the top. However, not all pages actually mention this.

An easy solution would be to look at the title of the page (for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_(disambiguation)). However, not all disambiguated pages contain the word 'disambiguation' in their title: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom.

So, to conclude, does anyone know of a way to differentiate Wikipedia Disambiguation pages from Wikipedia pages with actual content?

EDIT: This isn't actually relevant to the question, but I'm programming in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to differentiate disambiguation pages from actual articles is that all disambiguation pages are members of the hidden category [Category:All disambiguation pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aAll_disambiguation_pages).

But parsing the actual HTML is probably not a good idea. You should use [the API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) instead. Using that, you can check for membership in a category or get article text. Many languages already have libraries for communication with the API, but I haven't found one for objective C.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. If anyone needs a Wikipedia API link for this, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Freedom&prop=categories&clcategories=Category:All%20disambiguation%20pages

Comment: No longer true with Disambiguator extension

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on categories, it is now possible to get this directly from the API using `?action=query&prop=pageprops`

Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&format=json&titles=Ekeby will return:

`{"query":{"pages":{"24789600":{"pageid":24789600,"ns":0,"title":"Ekeby","pageprops":{"disambiguation":"","wikibase_item":"Q410694"}}}}}`